# How to make camera ignore an object (my case: wall) when rendering?

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm using 3dsmax and vray as my renderer. I want to take an interior scene but have a trouble when I render it because the camera render the wall as well and cannot see through it (I cannot delete the wall behind the camera because it keeps messing up my light setting).

How can I hide the wall from camera (but not from the scene)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on object -> Object Properites -> Renderable